# having ambiguity using customized kernel for `sklearn.svm` regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I want to use customized kernel function in [Epsilon-Support Vector Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html)  module of `Sklearn.svm`. I found this code as an example for customized kernel for svc at [the scilit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
                  # avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
Y = iris.target


def my_kernel(X, Y):
    """
    We create a custom kernel:

                 (2  0)
    k(X, Y) = X  (    ) Y.T
                 (0  1)
    """
    M = np.array([[2, 0], [0, 1.0]])
    return np.dot(np.dot(X, M), Y.T)


h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data.
clf = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
clf.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired, edgecolors='k')
plt.title('3-Class classification using Support Vector Machine with custom'
      ' kernel')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

I want to define some function like:

```
def my_new_kernel(X):
    a,b,c = (random.randint(0,100) for _ in range(3))
    # imagine f1,f2,f3 are functions like sin(x), cos(x), ...
    ans = a*f1(X) + b*f2(X) + c*f3(X)
    return ans
```

What I thought about **kernel method** is that it's a function that gets **matrix of features** (`X`) as input and returns a **matrix of shape (n,1)** . Then **svm** appends the **returned matrix** to the **feature columns** and uses that to classify the labels **`Y`**.

In the code above the kernel is used in `svm.fit` function and I can't figure out **what are `X` and `Y` inputs of kernel and their shapes**. if `X` and `Y` (inputs of `my_kernel` method) are the features and label of dataset, so then how does the kernel work for test data where we have no labels?

Actually I want to use svm for a dataset with shape of `(10000, 6)`, (5 columns=features, 1 column = label) then if I want to use `my_new_kernel` method what would be the inputs and output and their shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact issue is quite unclear; here are some remarks which may be helpful nevertheless.

> I can't figure out what are X and Y inputs of kernel and their shapes. if X and Y (inputs of my_kernel method) are the features and label of dataset,

Indeed they are; from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.fit) of `fit`:

> **Parameters:**
>
> **X : *{array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)***
>
> Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features. For kernel=”precomputed”, the
>   expected shape of X is (n_samples, n_samples).
>
> **y : *array-like, shape(n_samples,)***
>
> Target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in regression)

exactly like they are for the default available kernels.

> so then how does the kernel work for test data where we have no labels?

A close look at the code you have provided will reveal that the labels `Y` are indeed used only during training (`fit`); they are not of course used during prediction (`clf.predict()` in the code above - don't get confused with `yy`, which have nothing to do with `Y`).

Comment: what about the output of `my_kernel` function? what is the shape like?(n_samples, n_samples?)

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam not quite sure by just reading the code, but should be straightforward to see it for yourself with an experiment (although the `np.dot` makes me think it should be a scalar).